# C# Красивая упаковка доп. файлов из чужого nuget

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

У меня есть сборка - exe-шник и несколько dll для работы с программой. Устанавливал их из Nuget. Есть способ красиво упаковать эти файлы в отдельную папку (чтобы они не мешались с самой программой) и, желательно, их переименовать?

Comment: Можете упаковать всё в один exe утилитой ilmerge.